# Leaflet geosearch: return lat/lng from address found event

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geocoding

I use great Leaflet plugins for geocoding such as https://github.com/smeijer/L.GeoSearch

While these are perfect for showing address locations on the map when found, I would also like to be able to use the coordinates from the result to other functions that I have included in my map (e.g. I've written one which finds nearby points from a data layer based on the `locationfound` event fired from Leaflet's inbuilt `locate` function).

I know the answer (probably) lies in accessing the events from the geosearch plugin, but that's a bit beyond my skills at the moment. Any help would be very welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `L.GeoSearch` plugin fires it's events on your map instance. You'll need to listen for the `geosearch_foundlocations` event. The object that's returned when the event is fired holds a `Locations` property which contains an array with `L.GeoSearch.Result` objects. Each object has four properties; `Label`, `X`, `Y` and `bounds`

Example in code:

```
map.on('geosearch/showlocation', function (e) {
    e.Locations.forEach(function (Location) {
        // Location.Label = full address
        // Location.X = longitude
        // Location.Y = latitude
        // Location.bounds = boundaries
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi. Why It doesn't work using `geosearch_foundlocations` in version 3.2.1? How to do that to achieve result of searching query?

Comment: @koderstory Please use "geosearch/showlocation" event